# java class is compiled but not run in debian

Tags: java, exception, jar, noclassdeffounderror

I have the next problem. I use MinGW in windows. Here java works great. I tried to lounch java program in debian and got unpredictable result. Here is my code:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTPClient;
import org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTPReply;
public class FTPConnectAndLoginDemo {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String server = "192.168.253.130";
        int port = 21;
        String user = "ovod88";
        String pass = "taon88";
        FTPClient ftpClient = new FTPClient();
        try {
            ftpClient.connect(server, port);
            showServerReply(ftpClient);
            // int replyCode = ftpClient.getReplyCode();
            // if (!FTPReply.isPositiveCompletion(replyCode)) {
            //     System.out.println("Operation failed. Server reply code: " + replyCode);
            //     return;
            // }
            // boolean success = ftpClient.login(user, pass);
            // showServerReply(ftpClient);
            // if (!success) {
            //     System.out.println("Could not login to the server");
            //     return;
            // } else {
            //     System.out.println("LOGGED IN SERVER");
            // }
    } catch (IOException ex) {
            System.out.println("Oops! Something wrong happened");
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private static void showServerReply(FTPClient ftpClient) {
        String[] replies = ftpClient.getReplyStrings();
        if (replies != null && replies.length > 0) {
            for (String aReply : replies) {
                System.out.println("SERVER: " + aReply);
            }
        }
    }            
}
```

This program compiles like this (needed jar is in my home directory):

```
javac -cp /home/ovod88/commons-net-3.1.jar FTPConnectAndLoginDemo.java
```

But it is not running((( I found at this site and many other solutions like adding -classpath . or -cp . to run command like:

```
java -cp /home/ovod88/commons-net-3.1.jar FTPConnectAndLoginDemo
```

or

```
java -cp . FTPConnectAndLoginDemo
```

or

```
java -classpath .  FTPConnectAndLoginDemo
```

None works((( Its combinations also didnt work((( The error is:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/net/ftp/FTPClient
        at FTPConnectAndLoginDemo.main(FTPConnectAndLoginDemo.java:11)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTPClient
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:217)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:205)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:323)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:294)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:268)
        ... 1 more
```

Comment: did you check if the jar content is good? Is it corrupted?  try jar tf </home/ovod88/commons-net-3.1.jar>

Comment: Try `java -cp /home/ovod88/commons-net-3.1.jar:. FTPConnectAndLoginDemo` - you need both the jar file and the current directory in your CLASSPATH.

Comment: Thanks Paul!!!!It works!!! I spent about two hours trying((( Java)))

Comment: Why there is no such problem in minGW? Strange. Probably I did something)))

Comment: Probably on your Windows machine, the `CLASSPATH` environment variable is set and includes an entry for the `commons-net` library.